Show a Plan as a Tab inside Teams Channel is no more working using Graph API, any advice?
I  have this work flow which create a new Team Channel + create a new Planner Plan + show the Planner Plan as a tab inside the Team Channel. this was working well for around 6 months, but recently it stop working as expected.
Here is my workflow:-



here is the "Body of the request" for showing the plan as a tab inside channel action:-
{
    "displayName": "@{outputs('Compose_-_Friendly_Planner_Name')}",
    "teamsApp@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.planner",
    "configuration": {
        "entityId": "@{body('Invoke_an_HTTP_request_-_Create_new_Channel')?['id']}",
        "contentUrl": "https://tasks.teams.microsoft.com/teamsui/{tid}/Home/PlannerFrame?page=7&auth_pvr=OrgId&auth_upn={userPrincipalName}&groupId={groupId}&planId=@{variables('PlannerID')}&channelId={channelId}&entityId={entityId}&tid={tid}&userObjectId={userObjectId}&subEntityId={subEntityId}&sessionId={sessionId}&theme={theme}&mkt={locale}&ringId={ringId}&PlannerRouteHint={tid}",
        "removeUrl": "https://tasks.teams.microsoft.com/teamsui/{tid}/Home/PlannerFrame?page=13&auth_pvr=OrgId&auth_upn={userPrincipalName}&groupId={groupId}&planId=@{variables('PlannerID')}&channelId={channelId}&entityId={entityId}&tid={tid}&userObjectId={userObjectId}&subEntityId={subEntityId}&sessionId={sessionId}&theme={theme}&mkt={locale}&ringId={ringId}&PlannerRouteHint={tid}",
        "websiteUrl": "https://tasks.office.com/{tid}/Home/PlanViews/@{variables('PlannerID')}?Type=PlanLink&Channel=TeamsTab"
    }
}

Currently when i click on the new tab i will not get the new planner tasks, i will rather get "My Tasks",as follow:-

previously i use to get the related Planner tasks as follow:-

any advice, why this is no loner working as it use to be?
Thanks
